# How to initialise a Class using the C#12 Primary Constructor

Tags: c#, c#-12.0, primary-constructor

How do you initialise a class using the C#12 primary construtor syntax.
I know how to do it using dependency injection but cant find any docs showing how to do it with a normal class.

here is what I want to change to the primary constructor syntax.

```
internal class AutoHttpClient : IAutoHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public AutoHttpClient()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

}
```

im guessing that just doing the below will not work or will it?

```
internal class AutoHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient) : IAutoHttpClient
{
}
```

I have also looked onlint but all the examples aside of DI were using base types like int etc.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will need to keep the field and initialise it: `class AutoHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient): IAutoHttpClient { readonly HttpClient httpClient = httpClient; }`

Comment: You didn't have the client as a ctor argument to begin with. Why do you now? If you want an exact equivalent: that's not it.

Comment: Sorry but...what is exactly your question? What are you trying to achieve and where are you failing at?

Comment: _"im guessing that just doing the below will not work or will it?"_ what makes you think that? I am not aware of any restrictions to what can be used as an argument that are tighter than for normal ctors.

Comment: @Ergis was your question for me

Comment: Yes. What are you trying to achieve and where are you stuck? Because I find it confusing. You have the first version, trying to convert it to c# 12 primary constructor syntax version? Or what

Comment: @Ergis apologies if my explanation was not clear. I thought it was. My first example is the original syntax of how you would new up a class using a constructor. My question is very simple whats the syntax to do it using a primary constructor? Ignore my second example it was just to show how far i have gotten in trying to convert my first example to the new Primary constructor syntax. Does that make sense and do you have an answer?

Comment: With the 2nd version: its still just a constructor. Besides did you try writing it yourself? I did and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example works just fine:

```
internal class AutoHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    public async Task SendRequestAsync()
    {
        await httpClient.GetAsync("url");
    }
}
```

Note that in this case `httpClient` is basically a closed-over variable, and not a named private readonly field. If you want to prevent the internal code from changing the value of `httpClient` after construction, you'll need to declare a separate field. But you can still initialize it from the primary constructor's parameter.

```
internal class AutoHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient = httpClient;
    public async Task SendRequestAsync()
    {
        await httpClient.GetAsync("url");
    }
}
```

In this case, the field overrides the variable name `httpClient`, so the compiler doesn't make the closure field available in your methods: only in the field initializers. So when the method references `httpClient` it's referencing the declared field instead.